# Is there a way to extract all the work items affected of a risk in Rally using REST API?

Tags: rest, api, powerbi, rally

We have been using Power Bi to access our Rally backlog (Features, User stories).  We are planning on including risks and milestones to the extract.   We are currently able to successfully retrieve the risks and milestones but not the work items affected by them.  Example is Risk RI000 that affects user stories US00000 and US00001.

We want retrieve the 2 work work items affected (US00000, US00001) along with the risk (RI000).

Comment: Please share some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Rally stores WorkAffectedItems as a JSON Web file. From Risks, pull the "WorkItemsAffected.ref" column and you can convert it to a JSON record.

```
Table.AddColumn(#"PREVIOUS STEP", "WorkItemsAffected", each Json.Document(Web.Contents([WorkItemsAffected._ref])))
```

You'll then be able to expand the column like you would a normal Record to drilldown to the Formatted ID or whatever you need.